# 2nd update query not working even interchanging wont work

Tags: php, mysql

i have this php code which update status of my domains in my database. the problem is the second update line is not updating only the 1st one. please help me i know this is simple but i am quite stuck. i also tried interchanging them but still wont work status wont update to flagged

```
<?php
    $availdom = 'test.com';
    $flagDomain = 'example.com';
    $con=mysqli_connect("server","user","pass","Domain");// Check connection
        if (!$con){die("Connection error: " . mysqli_connect_error());}


            $sql = "UPDATE domaintracker SET Status='In use' WHERE Domain='$availdom'";
            $result = mysqli_query($con, $sql) or die(mysqli_error($con));
            $sql = "UPDATE domaintracker SET Status='Flagged' WHERE Domain='$flagDomain'";
            $result = mysqli_query($con, $sql) or die(mysqli_error($con));
    ?>
```

Table:

```
Domain     | Account | Status
test.com   | myacc   | Available
example.com| myacc   | In use
```

here is the table so i want to update test.com status to In use, and example.com status to Flagged

Comment: Can you show what's in the table? Also you should consider using PDO and prepared statements.

Comment: thanks for your response please see updated post for the table .

Comment: Is your code is not throwing an error?

Comment: the only problem i see is your opening php tag `<?` should be `<?php` , other than that all should work. What do you see? any errors?

Comment: Can you share your database table's schema?

Comment: @jay nope no error on the code

Comment: Does code execution continue beyond the first $result line? Have you stepped through, or tried putting an echo "hello world" after the first $result line?

Comment: @DavidFindlay yes it does i tried that already i even tried to exchange the 1st update line to the 2nd update still its still its only updating the test.com domain and not the example.com

Comment: Make sure the values stored in your Domain don't contain spaces or non-printing characters or something like that. Try testing the UPDATE manually in the mysql query tool instead of in PHP code. And as David said, please use parameterized queries instead of interpolating variables in your SQL string.